# Android In-App billing queries

Tags: android, in-app-billing

So after reading [this](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/) tutorial, and also going through [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html), I was trying to implement the in-app billing. I had 2 questions

1) One thing that I don't understand is where do I get the `BASE_64_KEY`. I have a correct draft in the developer console, and there is a `BASE_64_PUBLIC_KEY` over there. Is this the same one that I require in the in-app billing?

2) The Android documentation says `You cannot use the Android emulator to test In-app Billing`. I am using GenyMotion (with Google Apps added through the tweak on XDA website) and do not have a physical Android device. Is testing using Genymotion a good idea?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the public key for your application. As described [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-security), you can find it in the details for the application under "Services & APIs".

Regarding testing with GenyMotion, I can't speak to that directly, as I haven't used it. But from what I've read, I have my doubts. Certainly you can't use it out of the box; it does not include a recent version of Google Play, which is required for testing in-app billing. I found [this blog post](http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/) on how to install Google Play, but I have no idea if it will actually work.

Comment: So both the keys are the same? Then if it is a public key why do we need to secure it? Or rather, why is it called public? (Also I updated teh question to say that I do have GenyMotion with Google Apps).

Comment: @rgamber - Yes, it's the same key. It's public only in the sense that it's public to you. The matching private key is secreted away inside the Google servers. You should treat the public key as sensitive data (as described [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html#key)). As I said, I don't know if installing Google Apps is enough to test in-app billing. Just go ahead and try it; the worst that can happen is that the testing fails. For our own testing, we bit the bullet and bought a second-hand Nexus, which is basically dedicated to that one purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I get it! Yeah, so I quickly tried the testing using GenyMotion with a test accoung, and it seems to work fine. But will still somehow test it on a real device. Getting a Nexus phone or a tablet might be a good idea.

Comment: Genymotion emulators with Google Apps (there are two currently - one for phone and one for tablet) work with Google Play service, hence the testing of in-app billing.